# Error: Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data type (Date/Time)

Tags: workflow, formula

I have this formula:

```
NOW()  -  Lead_Escalation_from_Production__c
```

And this is what the `Lead_Escalation_from_Production__c` field holds (our business hours):

```
IF(MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900,1,7),7) = 6, 
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate + 2)) & " 12:00:00"), 

IF(MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900,1,7),7) = 0, 
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate + 1)) & " 12:00:00"), 

IF(MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900,1,7),7) = 5 && CreatedDate > DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) & " 22:00:00"), 
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate + 3)) & " 12:00:00"), 

IF(CreatedDate > DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) & " 22:00:00"), 
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate + 1)) & " 12:00:00"), 

IF(CreatedDate < DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) & " 12:00:00"), 
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) & " 12:00:00"), 

CreatedDate)))))
```

I am using a workflow rule that if the lead status is not open or has been converted i want it to do the formula above,NOW()  -  Lead_Escalation_from_Production__c, but I get the error message:Error: Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data type (Date/Time)

I would like to use now since it will get a closer time

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks exactly the same, what did you change?

Comment: He changed the number he adds to the CreatedDate

Comment: From the initial look, the formula `NOW() - Lead_Escalation_from_Production__c` has return type `Date/Time` but it is actually returning the difference in number of days. So, you might have to change the return type to `Number` if that is what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add a day, I suspect that's why you're getting the above error. In this part of your formula:

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate + 1))
```

`CreatedDate +1` results in a number. You want to get the `day(CreatedDate)` or `Month(CreatedDate)` or `Year(CreatedDate)` before adding a number to it. You also want to remove the `TEXT` from this because you're returning TEXT Values, not numerical values that you do addition with!